# React/Typescript multimap

Tags: reactjs, typescript, multimap

I'm new to typescript and not able to figure out how to implement a multimap. I have the code as below. I need to iterate through the itemArray and store the Item according to date. I need to use the date as the key to the multimap. How to go about implementing this without using any external libraries?

```
interface Item {
    id: number;
    date: string;
}

interface Details{
    itemArray: Item[]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this, [`Map`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [indexable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

## Indexable Types

Indexable types are basic objects with their keys and values typed.:

```
interface ItemMap {
    [key: string]: Item[];
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=12&ssc=3&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyRywAJgFzIgCuGARtANwHHKlySUDOYUoA5s3wBfAgVCRYiFABEIYOMAA2XHC2LBMAQShQ4AT0roIGANoBdIaPzjw0eEjSYAsnAAOawsVMBrCIeQePhB+cyNMCyshAhhqEAQwYAB7EBJJDggAClJ5RRVKOQVlLgBKcJNXDzwvIiV5ZAx3coxK5ABeHGEhVhyilQA6TRMdPX1+mCSoAFFEAAtMzKGMEvaAPk9WVmAYZEXMfvZIElTGtxXqzcuG91Mlg4zzfrdqLnmlku6r4WQIFRQLq6sU63faHCDmdrIEEmSzqS7WVjCD5w5BQeTUKAndxWIA)

## Maps

Maps are a JS class that implements a hash map - This method is useful when indexing by non-string/number types.

```
type ItemMap = Map<string, Item[]>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyRywAJgFzIgCuGARtANwHHKlySUDOYUoA5s3wBfAgVCRYiFABEIYOMAA2XHC2LBMAQShQ4AT0roIGANoBdIaPwEw+gA4pjGALJx7yALzI39gDw8fCD8ADRomBYAfGL4MNQgCGDAAPYgJJIcEAAUpPKKKpRyCspcAJRGmL5qhMRK8sgY7hUmVd4gEADuPu5ZpUKsucUqAHSaJjp6+sMwyVAAoogAFllZYxilXpHVrKzAMMhZjfbDi3Bcq5jD7JClG3g1OzuH7sP88hcmV5kbAPw-yBZSsN7NQuMs1n11I9hMgICoUPdHo8jsMuO81l9IGFTGtzJCHjtrKxhPjWFB5NQoGkjlYgA)

Answer (score 0):

Some packages offer multimap classes, but I found this sufficient for my task:

```
type MultiMap<KEY, VALUE> = Map<KEY, Array<VALUE>>;

function mmAdd<KEY, VALUE>(mm: MultiMap<KEY, VALUE>, key: KEY, value: VALUE) {
    const values = mm.get(key);
    if (values === undefined) {
        mm.set(key, [value]);
    } else {
        values.push(value);
    }
}

function usage() {
    const mmap: MultiMap<string, string> = new Map();
    mmAdd(mmap, 'key1', 'value1');
    mmAdd(mmap, 'key1', 'value2');
    mmAdd(mmap, 'key2', 'value3');
}
```